# Theme changes after resuming from suspend

Tags: 10.10, graphics, suspend-resume

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 1520 and Ubuntu 10.10. I've read a lot of questions about graphics problems after resuming from suspend, but most of them are much more serious than mine. I can boot, login and use Ubuntu fine. The problem is that my theme for my top bar and bottom bar changes to gray and blocky (not rounded). Oddly enough, the theme for the title bars of my windows stay the same dark theme. Any ideas how I can fix this? It works fine if I logout and log back in.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the gnome-settings-daemon is crashing upon resume from suspend, which could be this [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/551809) (probably caused by libappindicator).

Comment: Hm ok. I guess I'll wait and hope for a bug fix.